# From AbstractMesh to Mesh in BabylonJS

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I have a little problem:
I would like to use CSG on mesh imported using assetsmanager, everythins work ok but I cant reach to have a CSG object, that I think it's because I have an abstractmesh and not a mesh,
So how to convert AbstractMesh to mesh? My bad part of code is that:

```
assetsManager.onFinish = function(task)
        {
            var prova = task[0].loadedMeshes[0];
            aCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(prova);
```

I get "Cannot read property '0' of null", that I think because loadeMeshes return an Array of AbstractMesh as the documentation here:  https://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.meshassettask#loadedmeshes
but BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh() method need a Mesh type as you can see in the documentation here: https://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.csg#frommesh

Could someone help me?

Thnak you

Comment: facing the same issue, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the issue. Can you make sure that prova object is the mesh that you want? sometimes they are non geometric root meshes